# Types of variable lookups in javascript

Tags: javascript, compilation

Watching the wonderful "Advanced Javascript" by Kyle Simpson, I am having a hard time grasping the different variable lookups in the language. From what I have grasped so far, there are basically two ones:

- Scope Chain
- Prototype Chain

The third one would argue to be the **this** invocation, right?

I understand that the scope chain is done in compilation time (with the AST tree and so on) but what about the others? I undarstand that the **this** binding is determined by the invoking of the functon, ie execution time, but what about the prototype?

Sorry if this is an obvious question or has been asked before, but this is a fundamental thing that I really want to understand. thanks

Comment: The properties of `this` are looked up by the prototype chain. It's determined at execution time.

Comment: Interesting question. Objects and prototype chains can be created conditionally. `this` is dynamically bound to the object it is called on. Both strong indicators that prototype chains are evaluated dynamically at run-time. Modern engines may have strategies to avoid property look ups in rare cases by evaluating prototype chains statically. But that would be an implementation detail.

Comment: thanks so much. and closure is the ability to access the scope chain even outside of the scope chain. my eyes have been opened now